# When installing a component in Joomla 3.2.1 it is giving the error Archive does not exist.

Tags: joomla

Warning
JFolder::create: Could not create directoryPath: D:\wamp

Warning: Failed to move file!

JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: D:\wamp\www\acreindia\tmp\install_5309b76219b0a

JFolder: :folder: Path is not a folder. Path: D:\wamp\www\acreindia\tmp\install_5309b76219b0a

JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: D:\wamp\www\acreindia\tmp\install_5309b76219b0a

JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file

Error
Archive does not exist

Comment: check if the directory `D:\wamp` is not read-only

Answer (score 0):

Please check your owner and usergroup of folder.

1. For Apache it must be www-data for owner and usergroup.
   Log in to your server via ssh --> Go to your web directory like /var/www / your Joomla kit Write command here as :->  ls-alt

This will show all details.
If its not www-data then place this command.

**sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www**

1. Folders must have 755
2. Files must have 644 permission

Else you can check server error.log or access .log at /var/log/apache2/